# Split java.util.Date collection by Days

Tags: java, date

Could you help me, please. I can't figure out the algorithm.

I have a sorted collection of Dates, for example ArrayList like this:

```
Wed Jan 22 00:00:00 MSK 2014
Wed Jan 22 00:30:00 MSK 2014
Wed Jan 23 01:00:00 MSK 2014
Wed Jan 23 01:30:00 MSK 2014
Wed Jan 23 02:00:00 MSK 2014
Wed Jan 24 02:30:00 MSK 2014
Wed Jan 24 03:00:00 MSK 2014
Wed Jan 24 03:30:00 MSK 2014
Wed Jan 24 04:00:00 MSK 2014
Wed Jan 28 04:30:00 MSK 2014
Wed Jan 28 05:00:00 MSK 2014
```

I need another version of this list, grouped by day (from 00:00:00 till 23:59:59), so it could be an array of lists, like `List<List<Date>>`. Following the example it should be the list with size 4, with second Object ==

```
List<Date> {Wed Jan 23 01:00:00 MSK 2014;
Wed Jan 23 01:30:00 MSK 2014;
Wed Jan 23 02:00:00 MSK 2014; }
```

Seems like an easy task. but I can't find convenient way to solve it. Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**
According to TEXHIK's answer, width JDK 7 it could be done like this:

```
 public List<List<Date>> split(List<Date> value) {
        List<List<Date>> result = new ArrayList<>();

        int day = value.iterator().next().getDate();
        List<Date> newListEntry = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Date date : value) {
            if (date.getDate() == day) {
                newListEntry.add(date);
            }
            else {
                day = date.getDate();
                result.add(newListEntry);
                newListEntry = new ArrayList<>();
                newListEntry.add(date);
            }
        }
        result.add(newListEntry);//because the last sublist was not added

        return result;
    }
```

It's OK, unless it's deprecated methods of java.util.Date. Will be glad to see the answers using Java 8 or Joda Time.

Comment: Grouped by day in what time zone? Your local time zone? Are you able to use Joda Time or java.time from Java 8? Both of those will be a *lot* cleaner than using `java.util.Date`.

Comment: Supposing UTC TimeZone, actually it doesn't matter. Joda Time yes, Java 8 no. It would be better, if it's could be done with JDK 7.

Comment: why not use a TreeMap or a HashMap and collect a list of date-times by date

Comment: "collect a list of date-times by date" this is what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @user3523579 , Check out my answer with java 8 and guava

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're happy with UTC days, life becomes simpler:

- The milliseconds-since-the-unix-epoch starts on a day boundary, so you can just divide
- Each day is 24 hours long, which is handy in many cases (e.g. if you're doing analytics with the data)

In that case, you can just use something like:

```
long millisPerDay = TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1);
Map<Long, List<Date>> datesByDay = new HashMap<>();
for (Date date : dates) {
    long day = date.getTime() / millisPerDay;
    List<Dates> dayDates = datesByDay.get(day);
    if (dayDates == null) {
        dayDates = new ArrayList<>();
        datesByDay.put(day, dayDates);
    }
    dayDates.add(date);
}
```

Of course, a `Multimap`, e.g. from [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava), will make this simpler:

```
long millisPerDay = TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1);
Multimap<Long, Date> datesByDay = ArrayListMultimap.create();
for (Date date : dates) {
    long day = date.getTime() / millisPerDay;
    datesByDay.put(day, date);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer that might be interesting from a Java 8 point of view.  This example uses the streams API as well as `java.time.*`:

```
  public static List<List<Date>> split(List<Date> value) {
    return new ArrayList<>(value.stream().sorted().collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(
            // Group by LocalDate converted from Date
            d -> d.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate(),
            // Group into a LinkedHashMap to preserve encounter order
            LinkedHashMap::new,
            // We want the grouped elements in a List
            Collectors.toList())).values());
  }
```

Here is a unit test for same:

```
  @Test
  public void testSplit() {
    final int TEST_DAYS = 9;
    final int TEST_HOUR_STEP = 8;
    final int TEST_DATES_PER_DAY = 24 / TEST_HOUR_STEP;

    // Generate test data
    List<Date> dateList = new ArrayList<>();
    final int yy = 2015;
    final int mm = 2;
    for (int dd = 1; dd < 1 + TEST_DAYS; ++dd) {
      for (int h = 0; h < 24; h += TEST_HOUR_STEP) {
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of(yy, mm, dd, h, 0, 0);
        dateList.add(Date.from(ldt.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant()));
      }
    }
    List<List<Date>> splitDates = split(dateList);

    // We should have TEST_DAYS lists
    assertEquals(TEST_DAYS, splitDates.size());

    for (List<Date> ld : splitDates) {
      // Each list should have TEST_DATES_PER_DAY elements
      assertEquals(TEST_DATES_PER_DAY, ld.size());

      // Each list should have a single distinct element when converted to LocalDate
      assertEquals(1, ld.stream()
          .map(d -> d.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate())
          .distinct()
          .count());
    }
  }
```

Comment: Very nice. Just 5 rows. I think my project really should be switched to Java 8. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to fill your new list until the day is equals. Because of your original list is sorted, there should be no errors.

```
int day;
List<Date> newListEntry = new ArrayList<Date>();
Iterator sourceIterator = your_original_list.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext())
{
    Date date = iterator.next();
    if (date.getDate() == day)
       newListEntry.add(date);
    else
    {
       day = date.getDate();
       your_new_list.add(newListEntry);
       newListEntry = new ArrayList<Date>();
       newListEntry.add(date);
    }
}
your_new_list.add(newListEntry);//because the last sublist was not added
```

Comment: Nice, but deprecated methods. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Use Calendar instead of Date, if you want. "Numbers may be any, the solution is strictly defined".

Answer (score 0):

public class SortBydate {

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    ArrayList<Date> ls = new ArrayList<Date>();
    HashMap<String , ArrayList<Date>> has = new HashMap<String , ArrayList<Date>>();


      SimpleDateFormat format1=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy/HH/mm/ss");
      try {
          ls.add(format1.parse("22/01/2014/00/00/00"));
          ls.add(format1.parse("22/01/2014/00/30/00"));
          ls.add(format1.parse("23/01/2014/01/00/00"));
          ls.add(format1.parse("23/01/2014/01/30/00"));
          ls.add(format1.parse("23/02/2014/02/00/00"));
          ls.add(format1.parse("24/02/2014/02/30/00"));

          ls.add(format1.parse("24/02/2014/03/00/00"));
          ls.add(format1.parse("24/02/2014/03/30/00"));
          ls.add(format1.parse("24/02/2014/04/00/00"));
          ls.add(format1.parse("28/02/2014/05/00/00"));
          ls.add(format1.parse("28/02/2014/00/30/00"));

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    Iterator<Date> it = ls.listIterator();

    while(it.hasNext())
    {
        Date dt = it.next();
        String date = dt.getDate() +"," + dt.getMonth() + "," + dt.getYear();

        if(has.containsKey(date))
        {
            has.get(date).add(dt);
        }
        else
        {
            has.put(date, new ArrayList());
            has.get(date).add(dt);
        }

    }

    Set set = has.entrySet();
    it = set.iterator();

    while(it.hasNext())
    {
        Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry)it.next();

        System.out.println(entry.getValue());
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

> Will be glad to see the answers using Java 8 or Joda Time.

I will use mixture of `Java 8 Time Library` and `Google Guava's Multimap`

```
List<LocalDateTime> list=new ArrayList<LocalDateTime>();
// Add the Sorted LocalDateTime into it ...........

Multimap<Integer, LocalDateTime> builder=ArrayListMultimap.create();
list.forEach(local -> builder.put(local.getDayOfMonth(),local));
```

Now just Iterate the Multimap and see your desired output

```
Set keySet = builder.keySet();
Iterator keyIterator = keySet.iterator();
while (keyIterator.hasNext() ) {
    Integer key = (Integer)keyIterator.next();
    List values=(List) builder.get(key);
    System.out.println(values);
}
```

**For Inputs**

```
2015-02-18T16:33:49.114
2015-02-18T17:33:49.114
2015-02-18T18:33:49.114
2015-02-18T19:33:49.114
2015-02-18T20:33:49.114
2015-02-19T17:33:49.114
2015-02-19T18:33:49.114
2015-02-19T19:33:49.114
2015-02-19T20:33:49.114
```

**Output:**

```
[2015-02-18T16:33:49.114,
 2015-02-18T17:33:49.114,
 2015-02-18T18:33:49.114,
 2015-02-18T19:33:49.114,
 2015-02-18T20:33:49.114]

[2015-02-19T17:33:49.114,
2015-02-19T18:33:49.114, 
 2015-02-19T19:33:49.114,
 2015-02-19T20:33:49.114]
```