# last value of sublist in freemarker

Tags: freemarker

I have a long date list with corresponding price values.
out of this list I need the last price of every month.
I sliced the list and tried to get the last value but cant!
please help.
here is part of the list:
[image]

here is my code:

```
<#assign new_list><#list reportData.daily as list><#if list?string('M')?number=6 && list?string('Y')?number=2017>${list?string("dd/MM/yyyy")}</#if></#list></#assign>${new_list?last}
```

if I remove the "?last" it will show me a sublist for all dates for June-2017 but once i add "?last" i get:

For "?last" left-hand operand: Expected a sequence, but this has evaluated to a string (wrapper: f.t.SimpleScalar):

Comment: Off topic: this is not a job you should do in the presentation layer.

Comment: ... in your backend do something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28578072/split-java-util-date-collection-by-days

Answer (score 2):

You get that error because `<#assign new_list>...</#assign>` captures the raw output printed, which is not a sequence. If you really have to do this in template, put an `#if` inside the `#list` which only prints the current item if the next one is in a different month. (You can peek at the next item inside `<#list xs as x>...</#list>` like `xs[x?index + 1]`) But, you aren't supposed to do such data processing in a template...

Comment: i cant get the whole "next month" thing. could you provide a syntax for it?

Comment: Not "next month", "next item". This gets the item after the current item (`x`): `xs[x?index + 1]`, so you can test if `x` is the last of its month.